# Navigating away from catalog pages gets 404 page

Tags: magento2, url

User is at -

http://randomCompany.net/rental/wheelchairs.html

not looking at any specific product, just at that catalog page, they click a new menu link from the navigation,  that leads to a CMS page --

http://randomCompany.net/diabetic-shoes (this is the url that should show)

but the user is show a 404 page and the url is

http://randomCompany.net/rental/diabetic-shoes

it is adding in the /rental/  which is not correct.

Note - Url's work fine from the base catalog page, this problem only happens from sub category pages. I have tried URL rewrites. I could not find anything in the database. Any one have any insight here?

Thanks!

Comment: Tried adding <base href="/"> in xml and to the index and to the bootstrap and still nothing. This is so weird !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

> topmenu.phtml

```
<li class="level0 nav-0 last level-top ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a href="/about-us" class="level-top ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span>About Us</span></a>
```

All the a href="" require the `/` before each link. Nothing to do with url rewrites or anything. I was just missing the `/`